# Php merge object array getting wrongly only merge last values

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I am trying to merge an object as follows from set of values which comes from database as follows:

```
$pooldetails = array();
$qstncount = 5;

for($i=0;$i<$qstncount;$i++){

        $stdClass = $DB->get_record_sql("SELECT * FROM {pool_objective} po WHERE (po.id = $randarray[$i])");    
        $pooldetails = (object) array_merge((array) $pooldetails, (array) $stdClass);
}
```

When I print outside as follows:

```
print_r($pooldetails);
```

I am getting only last value in this array. I mean the value of `$qstncoun=4` .First 4 values are missing.What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @ raina77ow you are right buddy my key values are same. How can I manage this. Can you suggest any method??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's expected actually. Quoting [**the docs**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value
>   for that key will overwrite the previous one.

To get the results combined, use [**array_merge_recursive()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) instead:

```
$arr1 = ['a' => 1];
$arr2 = ['a' => 2];
var_dump(array_merge($arr1, $arr2));
// ['a' => 2]
var_dump(array_merge_recursive($arr1, $arr2)); 
// ['a' => [1, 2]]
```

Be aware, however, of the following:

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the values for
>   these keys are merged together into an array, and this is done
>   recursively, so that if one of the values is an array itself, the
>   function will merge it with a corresponding entry in another array
>   too. **If, however, the arrays have the same numeric key, the later
>   value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.**

It probably doesn't matter in your case, however, as keys map to column names. So you can use something like...

```
$pooldetails = array();
$qstncount = 5;
for($i=0;$i<$qstncount;$i++){
   $stdClass = $DB->get_record_sql("SELECT * FROM {pool_objective} po WHERE (po.id = $randarray[$i])");    
   $pooldetails = array_merge_recursive($pooldetails, (array) $stdClass);
}
$pooldetails = (object) $pooldetails;
```

Comment: In my case I tried like this: `$pooldetails = (object) array_merge_recursive($pooldetails, (array) $stdClass);`. I am getting empty array as result!!

Comment: `(array) $pooldetails`. BTW, I failed to understand why are you doing this all the time, and not at the end of the loop.

Comment: what you mean buddy. How to do in end of the loop. Can you elaborate

Comment: Updated the answer with more details.

Comment: @ raina77ow same as previous getting last value only in array. please sort it out buddy, I got stuck for longtime in this problem

Comment: @Santhucool Check again. I've used array_merge there, while recommending _recursive version to you. )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90351/discussion-between-santhucool-and-raina77ow).